# Query users and count totals based on meta values

Tags: loop, users, meta-query, wp-user-query

Users can choose a value from a multiple choice checkbox on sign up. In this example the choices are Cat or Dog.

I have a WP User Query and want to count the amount of users that have each meta value, and display something like '45 Cat People, 15 Dog People'.

Below are two separate queries but I'd like to loop through the values and display using one foreach query but not sure how to access the meta value to do this. Also the ability to output the value name rather than hard coding it would be useful...

```
    <?php

    // Meta value 'Cats'

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query(array(
        'role' => 'Subscriber', 
        'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'favourite_animal',
            'value' => 'Cat',
        ),
      )
    ));

    $users = $user_query->get_results();
    $total = $user_query->get_total(); 

    echo $total . 'Cat people';


    // Meta value 'Dogs'

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query(array(
        'role' => 'Subscriber', 
        'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'favourite_animal',
            'value' => 'Dog',
        ),
      )
    ));
    
    $users = $user_query->get_results();
    $total = $user_query->get_total(); 

    echo $total . 'Dog people'; 
            
    ?>
```

Comment: To give you an answer, we need to know how you created checkboxes on sign up, where values stored, than it will be possible to get them, pass them as array in meta query and create one foreach loop to show results.

Comment: I'm using a plugin called Ultimate Member. The checkbox values are stored as serialzed arrays,

Comment: Great. Can you get this array?

Comment: Yep. global $wpdb;

     $results = $wpdb->get_results("
     SELECT user_id, meta_value as 'favourite_animal'
     FROM $wpdb->usermeta
     WHERE `meta_key` = 'favourite_animal' 
     ");

     var_dump($results);

Comment: Can you paste result of this array?

Comment: object(stdClass)[7391]
      public 'user_id' => string '38' (length=2)
      public 'organisation_type' => string 'a:1:{i:0;s:8:"Cat";}'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124664/discussion-between-user144271-and-anton).